# JQuery won't load; Failed to load/work? Please help a Noob out

Tags: jquery, load

I'm a noob, so forgive me for for asking such a dumb question but i watched alot of tutorials video and text. On the jquery website i copy n pasted, typed it and nothing! Chrome states that it failed under the network tab.

I tried (Isn't this correct?)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery located under the `js/` directory (with respect to the page you're viewing)?

Comment: Did you download and save jQuery into a file called `jquery.js`, which is located in a directory called `js` that's located within the same directory as the page that you've included the `<script>` tag on?

Comment: In addition to the other answers/comments: Only use the first line in your code example - the second is redundant and less specific.

Comment: It didn't work because Chrome can't find where "js/jquery.js" is located on your computer. "js/jquery.js" is a relative path so it resolves to a different path on your machine compared to the example you looked at.  You can use the google CDN to refer to jquery source files to get you going http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be using jQuery on a live site, let Google host jQuery. Their servers are faster and web browsers will cache jQuery, making your website load quicker:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Drop the `type="text/javascript"`. http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-levels#level-1

Comment: Is jQuery located under the js/ directory (with respect to the page you're viewing)? Yes it is. I have a folder w/ the index.html file then within that folder i have the js folder where javascript.js is being held.

Comment: `js/` refers to the `js` directory in the same folder as your current HTML file. `/js/` refers to the `js` folder in the *root* of your webserver. I'm not sure what you're asking, though...

Comment: Also, use Firebug or Google Chrome's Inspector and post any errors you get when your page loads. If your path is correct then it's a JS error.

Comment: Referring it to the google libraries page worked! I'm still confused on why it didn't load on my personal machine though? any thoughts? So should i put desktop/lesson-1/js/jquery? for it to load on my personal computer? All the answers raised my knowledge on so many levels! Thanks for everyone for helping a noob out. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `http:` in `src="//ajax.googleapis..."`

Comment: `//` tells the web browser to add in `http:` or `https:` automatically. It's shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked downloaded jquery and put it into a folder named js and are sure that the file are jquery.js?

You can use CDN insteed, change src to this URL:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

And only use one script tag...

Comment: In addition to the other answers/comments: Only use the first line in your code example - the second is redundant and less specific. So only use <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>?

Answer (score 0):

Test ur app with google CDN , in this way u dont have to worry abt the relative path and stuff. pointless to tell u mst hve active internet connection if using hosted copy of jQuery. If ur app runs fine then be sure that ur problem lies in the relative path, 
Moreover using hosted copy of jQuery give u additional benefits as stated by @Blender